# How can I prevent access to a file while it is being written to, and resume execution once the file has been written?

Tags: javascript, node.js, concurrency

When my server receives a request, I run my function `foo`. At some point during `foo`, I check whether some files (based on the request) exist on my machine, and I fetch remotely those that do not, saving them locally for potential use in future requests.

I run into problems if I receive multiple requests simultaneously that both reference the same file `bar` that does not exist on my server. Here is an example timeline of what happens:

1. Request 1 asynchronously checks for existence of `bar`
2. Request 2 asynchronously checks for existence of `bar`
3. Request 1 sees that `bar` does not exist, so it asynchronously downloads the file
4. Request 2 sees that `bar` does not exist, so it asynchronously downloads the file
5. Request 1 opens up a write stream to `bar` and asynchronously pipes the file response into this write stream
6. Request 2 opens up a write stream to `bar` and asynchronously pipes the file response into this write stream
7. Request 1 finishes writing the file, attempts to loads its contents (an image) using an image loading library, and ultimately throws an error.

This happens because the file contents are invalid, because the file is in the process of being overwritten by request 2.

I understand that solving this problem will likely involve file locking, so the first request that sees that the file is missing locally can create a lockfile to indicate to subsequent requests that it is already being fetched/written to. What I'm not sure about is how to make these subsequent requests wait until the file is done loading.

Should I use generator functions, and pause execution of my function if it sees that some other request is fetching this remote file? In that case, how would I resume it later? Do I have to maintain some global queue of paused requests?

Are there any resources that would help me better understand what to do here?

Comment: Is this a one server issue with no outside contention for the file?  Or is this a multi-server issue and/or there is also outside contention for the file.  The options are much simpler if it's a one server issue.  Also, please show relevant portions of whatever actual code you have because the details of how you check for the existence of the file (to prevent race conditions) is also important.

Answer (score 0):

You will need some form of synchronization. As long as you just have one NodeJS process running, the easiest way is to use JavaScripts single threaded behaviour:

```
  const fileLoading = new Map();

  async function getFile(id) {
    if(fileLoading.has(id)) {
      await fileLoading.get(id);
    } else {
     const load = (async function() {
        await fetchFile(id);
        fileLoading.remove(id);
     })();
     fileLoading.set(id, load);
     await load;
   }
   return await readFile(id);
 }
```